# Getting a different set of data every page refresh in Django

Tags: python, django

I'm looking to get the next `x` items in a query set in Django every page refresh.

Example:
`x` is a list of number's that I use to choose from the query set. As in

`for i in x:`
`q = Django.objects.filter(name=name)[i]`

`x = [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]`
I would like to get item's `[0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5]`. then on the next page refresh get item's `[6, 7, 8, 9, 0, 1]`. Notice that the list rolls over from the end to the beginning if there are not 6 more item's.

So far I'm getting the length of the Query set then using `x % 6` to see if I don't have to modify the list

It would also be nice if this is multi user friendly
Example of multi user:
`x` is the same as above. When user 1 loads the page they get `[0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5]`. Now user 2 loads the page and gets `[6, 7, 8, 9, 0, 1]`. User 1 now reloads and gets `[2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7]` and so on and so forth.

Comment: You could use GET method or you could create a cookie

Comment: I'm still new to Django so forgive me if this is a redundant question. How would I go about using the get method for this?

Comment: The problem with the GET method is that you have to specify the page that you want to get for example `?page=1` or `?page=2`, with the cookie you could create a counter for every request to the page

Comment: read this https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/topics/pagination/

Comment: Thanks. I looked in to pagination however I choose not to use it mainly because like you said above it needs a `?page=1`. I'll look in to cookies though.

Comment: What should happen if you reach the *end* of the set of objects?

Comment: It will go back to the begging of the list.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can work with a *cookie*, some information that is stored at the client's machine, and that you can update. In the cookie, you can for example store the index thus far, and subsequently update it. Like:

```
def some_view(request):
    nqs = qs.objects.filter(name=name).count()
    idx = int(request.COOKIES.get('current_index', 0))
    if idx+5 < nqs:
        qs = Django.objects.filter(name=name)[idx:idx+6]
        idx += 6
    else:
        qs = list(Django.objects.filter(name=name)[idx:nqs])
        idx += 6-nqs
        qs += Django.objects.filter(name=name)[:idx+6-nqs]
    response = render(request, 'some_template.html', {'qs': qs})
    set_cookie(response, 'current_index', str(idx+6))
    return response
```

We thus store a cookie under the name `'current_index'`, and each time fetch that cookie. In case the cookie does not exists, we use `0` as default value. Next we perform some operations to fetch the items: in case there are sufficient, we take a single slice, otherwise we use two slices.

We update the index by advancing it six places (using modulo in case we reach the end of the list), and set the cookie to the (new) value. We then return the response.

Here we set as a response a template rendering (by calling `render(..)`, but you can of course construct a custom HTTP response).

Comment: That is exactly what I was looking for! Thank you so much!